# How can I read a file line (integer) and sum the total from line A to line B?

Tags: c, scanf, fseek

Say, file1.dat contains:

```
123
545
3576
3453
345
34
...
123     //1000th line
```

I am having trouble trying to write the addNumbers function to calculate the total from line Begin (variable) to line End (variable). Each child process/pipe is to calculate its own portion of the file, adding each partial sum into a final total and printing that total.

Variable fileRead is a file object that is passed into the function.

I. E. 4 child processes, 1000 lines, each process does 250 lines.
Here is my working code. Any questions please ask.:

```
division = numberOfLines/numberOfPipes;
int begin = currentPipe*division;
int end = begin + division;

for(i=begin; i<end; i++)
{
    fseek(fileRead, begin, SEEK_CUR);
    while(fgets(line,sizeof line,fileRead)!= NULL)
    {
    total+= total + line;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Olaf removed unnecessary information. now someone will comment "please post code"

Comment: Please post code. You're going to need to write code that seeks to the approximate boundary between chunks, and then searches forward till it finds the newline. The newline location is the end of one chunk, and the byte after the newline is the beginning of the next chunk. So you need an array of `begin` and `end` values, and you need to compute those values before starting the threads. You can use `ftell` after each `fgets` to see if you've reached the end.

Comment: You need to ask a **specific** question that helps you get past the next thing that is blocking you. You can't just dump incomplete code and ask for it to be completed for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem... several problems, are here:

```
while(fgets(line,sizeof line,fileRead)!= NULL)
{
    total += total + line;
}
```

First is you're trying to use `char *line` as a number. That isn't going to work. Unlike higher level languages, C will not cast a string to a number. You need to do it explicitly, usually with [`atoi(line)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm).

Your C compiler should have warned you about the type mismatch which suggests you're not running with warnings on. Most C compilers will not have warnings on by default, you need to turn them on. Usually this is with `-Wall` like `cc -Wall -g test.c -o test`.

Next, `total += total + line;` means `total = total + total + line` and that's probably not what you meant (and if it is, you should write it out longhand to make that clear). I assume you meant `total += line`.

---

Putting them together...

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fileRead)!= NULL) {
    total += atoi(line);
}
```